# Get system time only

Tags: time, android-timepicker

How to obtain system time? I mean the time only, date is not included and I want it in 12 hour format.

I have tried many ways but I always got a system date (and I don't want the date, the time only).

Thanks.

Comment: If you're just using a `TimePicker` it shouldn't be showing the date at all anyway. It's unclear exactly what you mean by "I always got a system date" - got it where?

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't use TimePicker. I just want to get the time and display it on a textview.

Comment: How do you get it (read: what API do you call)?

Comment: That was my problem basically. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If you don't use TimePicker, why have you tagged your question "android-timepicker"? That's very confusing. How are you *trying* to display the time at the moment, and what's your source data?